# XHTML validation Error <script>

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In WordPress I am using this code in my functions `echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">` which causes this XHTML validator error:
**"an attribute value must be a literal unless it contains only name characters"**

I need this to be in my functions in WordPress, but also to be XHTML valid.  I don't know much about any kind of coding, I'm a CSS and HTML junkie.  Any help/

EDIT: REST OF THIS SECTION OF CODE:

```
if ($toggle == "no"){
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/tagmap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
echo "\n\n";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery('ul.links li.hideli').hide();
  jQuery('ul.links li.morelink').show();
  jQuery('a.more').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().siblings('li.hideli').slideToggle('fast');
     jQuery(this).parent('li.morelink').remove();
  });
});
</script>\n\n";
```

Comment: What you have does not look wrong.  Maybe something in the context is causing the error.  You can try single quotes around the value of the type attribute: `<script type='text/javascript'>` just in case.

Comment: Are you missing the end quote?  Or is that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: @Ray Toal - That is invalid xHTML. I'd rather do this: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">';`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong... I just edited my post to show more of the code.  I really appreciate any help.

Comment: The validation service should show you the exact character where this fails (Line #: Column #:)... please look at that and tell us what it says. As noted above it is probably something with string escaping and you should change your quoting style.

Comment: @LucasWynne: Line 21 is Google Analytics: `<!-- Google Analytics --><script type=\"text/javascript\">`. Your already correct snippet is included in Line 84.

Comment: Google Analytics is being called with `code`<?php echo get_option('to_ga_code'); ?>`code` in codes.php from functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to validate `<script type=\"text/javascript\">`, which is invalid... the validation service highlights the slash character for you at column 14. You cannot have a slash character before the open quote starts in `type=`.

### Update

Check the HTML source of your page which is what the validator is actually checking... line 21 Column 14 is where your Google Analytics code starts, not the jQuery code.

```
Line 20: <!-- Google Analytics -->
Line 21: <script type=\"text/javascript\">
```

You need to remove the slashes here.

Comment: It is still returning a validation error... or are my cookies really messed up in my browser? :-S   http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthemeforward.com%2Fdemo2%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Look at the generated HTML source code... line 21 is where your Google Analytics code starts, not where your jQuery code is. You need to change the quotes there.